# Приоритет стилей при включении двух внешних CSS файлов в HTML

Tags: css

В HTML-документ включены два внешних источника с описанием стилей (с помощью `link href=file.css`).

Для одного из классов стиль задан в обоих файлах, притом с перекрывающимися атрибутами. Существует ли возможность добиться сделать одно из этих описаний "приоритетным"?

Конкретика - при использовании `icefaces` стили страниц подгружены из файла `royale.css`, и среди них для ссылок (`.iceCmdLnk`) определён стиль у которого `color:black, text-decoration:none`.

Я тут же пытаюсь включить ещё собственный файл (`general.css`), в котором хочу переопределить цвет ссылок на более привычный (`color:blue, text-decoration:underline`). Пытаюсь менять включения двух файлов местами - но эффекта не наблюдаю - ссылки остаются чёрными, в firebug мои стили помечены "зачёркнутым" (естественно стили из `general.css` для других элементов, не перекрытых работают нормально).

Или я в чём-то глючу?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приоритет можно установить:

1. Указанием `!important` . Игнорируется IE.
2. Более детальным описанием элемента (`li .link` перекроет `.link`).
3. Порядком описания. Кто позже, тот и перекроет.

Answer (score 4):

> Если к одному элементу одновременно применяются противоречивые стилевые правила, то более высокий приоритет имеет правило, у которого значение специфичности селектора больше. Специфичность это некоторая условная величина, вычисляемая следующим образом. За каждый идентификатор (в дальнейшем будем обозначать их количество через a) начисляется 100, за каждый класс и псевдокласс (b) начисляется 10, за каждый селектор тега и псевдоэлемент (c) начисляется 1. Складывая указанные значения в определенном порядке, получим значение специфичности для данного селектора.
>
> `*              {} /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> специфичность = 0   */
>  li             {} /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> специфичность = 1   */
>  li:first-line  {} /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> специфичность = 2   */
>  ul li          {} /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> специфичность = 2   */
>  ul ol+li       {} /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> специфичность = 3   */
>  ul li.red      {} /* a=0 b=1 c=2 -> специфичность = 12  */
>  li.red.level   {} /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> специфичность = 21  */
>  #t34           {} /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> специфичность = 100 */
>  #content #wrap {} /* a=2 b=0 c=0 -> специфичность = 200 */`
>
> Встроенный стиль, добавляемый к тегу через атрибут style, имеет специфичность 1000, поэтому всегда перекрывает связанные и глобальные стили. Однако добавление !important перекрывает в том числе и встроенные стили.
>
> Если два селектора имеют одинаковую специфичность, то применяться будет тот стиль, что определен в коде ниже.

[Источник.](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie)

Answer (score 0):

Более приоритетный тот, который был включен последним, стиль же, заданный непосредственно в элементе (`<a style="color: red">слово</a>`) имеет **наивысший приоритет.**

Comment: Спасибо! Нужно было подтверждение этого факта, который я только подозревал. По Вашей подсказке стал рыть и обнаружил что icefaces переставляет два разных включения стилей, так что мой оказывался в начале файла, хотя по темплейту xhtml-ному шёл последним. Запихнул один в head другой в body - стало всё отлично. ;-)

Comment: чтобы поднять приоритет до небес нужно описать стиль непосредственно внутри елемента с пометкой !impotrant